# How to map object values in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I have an object like:

```
{ "contact": { "value": 0 },
  "temperature": { "value": 5} 
}
```

That I would like converted to

```
{ "contact": 0,
  "temperature": 5
}
```

And I would like to avoid a spread/map/merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$keys($){
  $: $lookup($$, $).value
}
```

You can check out this expression in [Stedi](https://stedi.com)'s JSONata Playground here: https://stedi.link/V67vnsh

Answer (score 1):

I know you wanted to avoid `$merge`, but this solution would also work and is relatively short:

```
$each($, function($v, $k) {{ $k: $v.value }}) ~> $merge
```

Check it out here: https://stedi.link/3tOCJHb